# How to catch IllegalStateException displayed in Firebase coming from Apollo GraphQL Android SDK

Tags: java, android, graphql, apollo, illegalstateexception

I'm unsure of how to catch this crash tracked in Firebase in our codebase which is coming from the Apollo GraphQL SDK for Android, version 2.5.12. I have also not been able to reproduce it. It seems to be similar to this issue: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android/issues/153. Though, that issue is from RealAppSync, not Apollo.

Because Apollo uses callbacks, is it even possible to catch and handle this IllegalStateException in our codebase? Below is the stacktrace.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Found: TERMINATED, but expected [ACTIVE, CANCELED]

com.apollographql.apollo.internal.RealApolloCall.responseCallback (RealApolloCall.java:367)
com.apollographql.apollo.internal.RealApolloCall$1.onFetch (RealApolloCall.java:287)
com.apollographql.apollo.internal.fetcher.CacheFirstFetcher$CacheFirstInterceptor$1.onFetch (CacheFirstFetcher.java:48)
com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloCacheInterceptor$1.run (ApolloCacheInterceptor.java:60)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [this issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/pull/4383), for which [a fix](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/pull/4383) is currently pending to be part of the next release of Apollo Android 2.x.